# IzPack 5.0.0 beta 8 + izpack_home

Tags: java, izpack

I tryed install izpack version 5.0.0 beta 8, but the compile fails with message:

> IZPACK_HOME is set incorrectly or Izpack could not be located.

I can see that the bat is loocking for one "standalone-compiler.jar" that don't exists in lib folder.

{edit}
Not shure if this is the right way. I commented two lines and added one:

```
REM set IZPACK_JAR=lib\standalone-compiler.jar
REM if exist "%IZPACK_HOME%\%IZPACK_JAR%" goto checkJava
goto checkJava
```

Also copied the "lcp.bat" from the older version.
{/edit}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the lines:

```
set IZPACK_JAR=lib\standalone-compiler.jar
if exist "%IZPACK_HOME%\%IZPACK_JAR%" goto checkJava
```

to:

```
rem set IZPACK_JAR=lib\standalone-compiler.jar
rem if exist "%IZPACK_HOME%\%IZPACK_JAR%" goto checkJava
```

and right below add:

```
goto checkJava
```

then copy the lcp.bat to the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standalone compiler anymore (see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Upgrading+from+Previous+Versions).

The script should indeed be fixed, could you have a look at it?

Cheers

Comment: @jponge Still a problem with the latest beta 5.0.0 beta 10

Answer (score 0):

Download and Copy the standalone-compiler.jar to lib folder, from [Izpack.org](http://izpack.org/downloads/).
Now Add this to `compiler.bat`

```
set IZPACK_HOME=path/to/Izpack
```